# calling setState from onClick JavaScript function not working

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I am trying to create a button that will make visible a form to edit any contact on my list. However, when I press the button, nothing happens.

I have the initial state set to

```
this.state = {
        contacts: [],
        showEditWindow: false,
        EditContactId: ''
    };
```

I added a function:

```
editContact = (id) => {
            this.setState({
                showEditWindow: true, EditContactId: {id}
            });
        };
```

and a column:

```
{
            title: "",
            key: "action",
            render: (record) => (
                <button onClick={() => this.editContact(record.id)}
                >
                    Edit
                    </button>
                )
        },
```

I imported EditContactModal and call it as

```
<EditContactModal reloadContacts={this.reloadContacts} 
                    showEditWindow={this.state.showEditWindow}
                    EditContactId={this.state.EditContactId}/>
```

If I manually set `this.state` to `showEditWindow:true`, the window appears; however, either `this.editContact(id)` is not being called or it is not changing the state.

Calling `this.deleteContact(id)` works fine, as does `setState` in `loadContacts()` and `reloadContacts()`

What I am doing wrong?

Below are the full components.

Contacts.jsx

```
import { Table, message, Popconfirm } from "antd";
import React from "react";
import AddContactModal from "./AddContactModal";
import EditContactModal from "./EditContactModal";

class Contacts extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        contacts: [],
        showEditWindow: false,
        EditContactId: ''
    };

    this.editContact = this.editContact.bind(this);
};

    columns = [
        {
            title: "First Name",
            dataIndex: "firstname",
            key: "firstname"
        },
        {
            title: "Last Name",
            dataIndex: "lastname",
            key: "lastname"
        },{
            title: "Hebrew Name",
            dataIndex: "hebrewname",
            key: "hebrewname"
        },{
            title: "Kohen / Levi / Yisroel",
            dataIndex: "kohenleviyisroel",
            key: "kohenleviyisroel"
        },{
            title: "Frequent",
            dataIndex: "frequent",
            key: "frequent",
        },{
            title: "Do Not Bill",
            dataIndex: "donotbill",
            key: "donotbill"
        },
        {
            title: "",
            key: "action",
            render: (record) => (
                <button onClick={() => this.editContact(record.id)}
                >
                    Edit
                    </button>
                )
        },
        {
            title: "",
            key: "action",
            render: (_text, record) => (
                <Popconfirm
                    title="Are you sure you want to delete this contact?"
                    onConfirm={() => this.deleteContact(record.id)}
                    okText="Yes"
                    cancelText="No"
                    >

                    <a type="danger">
                        Delete{" "}
                        </a>

                </Popconfirm>
                ),
        },
    ];


componentDidMount = () => {
    this.loadContacts();
}

loadContacts = () => {
    const url = "http://localhost:3000/contacts";
    fetch(url)
        .then((data) => {
            if (data.ok) {
                return data.json();
            }
            throw new Error("Network error.");
        })
        .then((data) => {
            data.forEach((contact) => {
                const newEl = {
                    key: contact.id,
                    id: contact.id,
                    firstname: contact.firstname,
                    lastname: contact.lastname,
                    hebrewname: contact.hebrewname,
                    kohenleviyisroel: contact.kohenleviyisroel,
                    frequent: contact.frequent.toString(),
                    donotbill: contact.donotbill.toString(),
                };

                this.setState((prevState) => ({
                    contacts: [...prevState.contacts, newEl],
                }));
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => message.error("Error: " + err));
        };

        reloadContacts = () => {
            this.setState({ contacts: [] });
            this.loadContacts();
        };

        deleteContact = (id) => {
            const url = `http://localhost:3000/contacts/${id}`;

            fetch(url, {
                method: "delete",
                })
                .then((data) => {
                    if (data.ok) {
                        this.reloadContacts();
                        return data.json();
                    }
                    throw new Error("Network error.");
                })
                .catch((err) => message.error("Error: " + err));
            };

        editContact = (id) => {
            this.setState({
                showEditWindow: true, EditContactId: {id}
            });
        };

        render = () => {
            return (
                <>

                <Table
                    className="table-striped-rows"
                    dataSource={this.state.contacts}
                    columns={this.columns}
                    pagination={{ pageSize: this.pageSize }}

                    />
                    <AddContactModal reloadContacts={this.reloadContacts} />
                    <EditContactModal reloadContacts={this.reloadContacts} 
                    showEditWindow={this.state.showEditWindow}
                    EditContactId={this.state.EditContactId}/>
                    </>
                );
        }

        }
            
            
export default Contacts;
```

EditContactModal.jsx

```
import { Button, Form, Input, Modal, Select } from "antd";
import React from "react";
import ContactForm  from './ContactForm';

const { Option } = Select;

class EditContactModal extends React.Component {
    formRef = React.createRef();
    state = {
        visible: this.props.showEditWindow,
    };

    onFinish = (values) => {
        const url = `http://localhost:3000/contacts/${this.props.EditContactId}`;
        fetch(url, {
            method: "put",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(values),
        })
            .then((data) => {
                if(data.ok) {
                    this.handleCancel();

                    return data.json();
                }

                throw new Error("Network error.");
            })
            .then(() => {
                this.props.reloadContacts();
            })
            .catch((err) => console.error("Error: " + err))
    };

    showModal = () => {
        this.setState({
            visible: true,
        });
    };

    handleCancel = () => {
        this.setState({
            visible: false,
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                {/*<Button type="primary" onClick={this.showModal}>
                                Create New + 
                                </Button>*/}

                <Modal
                    title="Edit Contact"
                    visible={this.state.visible}
                    onCancel={this.handleCancel}
                    footer={null}
                >

                <ContactForm />
            </Modal>    
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default EditContactModal;
```

Comment: You can know if it's being called by adding a ```console.log``` statement or your dev tools. But from a quick glance, you instantiate ```EditContactId: ''``` and then in your function you say ```showEditWindow: true, EditContactId: {id}``` with the curly braces. Do you want ```EditContactId: id```? The curly braces make ```EditContactId``` an object which wouldn't throw an error, but perhaps give unexpected results.

Comment: I agree with @sintribu, considering `EditContactId={this.state.EditContactId}` and `const url = \`http://localhost:3000/contacts/${this.props.EditContactId}\`;` in the child component.

Comment: Thanks - I did change ```{id}``` to ```id```, and added ```console.log('function called');```. It did log 'function called' each time I pressed an Edit button - I guess the issue is with the setState.

Comment: I think render function's record must precede _text{
            title: "",
            key: "action",
            render: (_text,record) => (
                <button onClick={() => this.editContact(record.id)}
                >
                    Edit
                    </button>
                )
        },

Comment: thanks...I added that back in, but still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

if your aim is to perform an update to the state object, you must not pass mutable data, but copy it instead into a new object.
this will allow the state changes to be picked up.

so, prefer `setState({ ...state, ...someObject })` over `setState(someObject)`.

Comment: How would that apply to ```this.setState({ showEditWindow: true, EditContactId: id});```?

Comment: `this.setState({...state, ...{showEditWindow: true, EditContactId: id}})`

Comment: ... or simply: `this.setState({...state, showEditWindow: true, EditContactId: id})`, which is equivalent but more succinct.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work either.